# Dockerizing go application from a git repo

Tags: git, docker, go

I have a main.go application in git , i need to create docker file and to run application in kubernetes cluster.

I created the docker file but i am not sure it is correct,
how can  add the main.go from git to the docker?

Assume that main.go is in A repo in git:

I created a docker file in same A repo (this is my docker file):

```
#  base image for Go
FROM golang:latest

RUN mkdir /app


ADD . /app

# Set the Current Working Directory inside the container

WORKDIR /app


# Build the Go app
RUN go get github.com/gorilla/mux
RUN go build -o app/main



#COPY / ./

# Command to run the executable

CMD ["/app/main"]
```

I created image --> How can i know it is correct what i am doing?
please help!

Comment: by running it maybe..?

Comment: Please accept an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do (i have restructured your Dockerfile as well).

Refer this - https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

```
#  base image for Go
FROM golang:latest

RUN mkdir /app

# Set the Current Working Directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

# Build the Go app
RUN go get github.com/gorilla/mux && go build -o app/main

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/main"]
```

You can run the image by doind

```
docker run -d <image>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another (and my preferred) option using the [builder pattern / multistage build pattern](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/), which results in a very tiny (a couple of MB) final Docker image that contains only your application and not the whole go toolchain, which is unnecessary.

There are a number of comments to make.

Below,

1. `/your/app/namespace` is the well-formatted path name to your app, like `github.com/jumana/myApp`
2. `myApp` is the name of your application. It's unusual to compile an app binary called `main`, call it the name of your app/repo for clarity.
3. I assume this is a server application of some kind, so you'll need to `EXPOSE` the port on the container that you expect to run the application on

An example `Dockerfile`, which would be in the same folder as your Go code:

```
FROM golang:1.13.5 AS builder
COPY . /go/src/your/app/namespace
WORKDIR /go/src/your/app/namespace
RUN go get && CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o myApp .

FROM scratch AS app
COPY --from=builder /go/src/your/app/namespace /opt/myApp/
WORKDIR /opt/myApp/
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "./myApp" ]
```

Comments:

1. Specify the actual Go version you want to use, not `:latest` because some day Go will release a breaking update and your app will break.
2. `COPY` your code, from the root of your git repo, directly into the container and build it there.
3. There should be no need to `go get` anything specific; just copy your code into the image and `go get` everything that your code needs with no arguments.
4. The [`scratch`](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch) image is a special minimal image that can run your app.
5. While you can put your app binary anywhere, `/opt/` is a common place to deploy it.

Comment: This is helpful. Multi-stage build is better approach. I would like to know what we need to add if a web app is developed using ECHO framework? Can we use this Dockerfile to deploy image to production server?

Answer (score 0):

Adding some information to the **@msanford's** answer.
If you are using Go Modules to manage dependencies then you can copy `go.mod` and `go.sum` files into the container,   download dependencies and then in continue with your build.

`Go 1.11` introduces the `go mod download` command, which takes `go.mod` and `go.sum` files and downloads the dependencies from them instead of using the source code. As these files generally don’t change very frequently (unless you are updating the dependencies), they **can be simply cached** by the `COPY` command from `Dockerfile` which can improve performance when you build the image next time.

Here is simplified **Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:1.13.5 AS builder

LABEL author="Muhammad"

# All these steps will be cached
WORKDIR /src

# Copy golang dependency manifests
COPY go.mod .  # COPY go.mod and go.sum files to the workspace
COPY go.sum .

# Dependencies will also be cached if we wont change mod/sum
RUN go mod download

# Add the source code
COPY . .

# Build
RUN go get && CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o myApp .

FROM scratch AS app
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /src .
EXPOSE 9080
ENTRYPOINT [ "./myApp" ]
```

References:

- https://petomalina.medium.com/using-go-mod-download-to-speed-up-golang-docker-builds-707591336888
- [Go dockerized build, cacheing the dependency pull layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61083819/go-dockerized-build-cacheing-the-dependency-pull-layer)

Answer (score -3):

Instead of the **CMD** command, you need an **ENTRYPOINT**  at the end of your script.

Here is an example I wrote that starts a Java Spring-Boot service:

https://github.com/djangofan/karate-test-prime-example/blob/master/Dockerfile-apibase