# Go dockerized build, cacheing the dependency pull layer

Tags: docker, go, skaffold

I'm having a ripping good time using `skaffold` to develop some kubernetes services, but one of the longest steps in my cycle is pulling all the dependencies for the container.

Does anyone have recommendations on how I can best cache all the dependencies in a layer? Are there best practices with building go binaries inside docker containers? Should I have a layer where I do a `go get`? (Also I'm a novice building go binaries, don't know all the bells and whistles yet.)

Comment: This might be useful. [Multi stage docker build for a Golang application with and without vendor directory](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/1sfg/multi-stage-docker-build-for-a-golang-application-with-and-without-vendor-directory)

Comment: You might want to look at ko, a Go-specific image builder that can be used with Skaffold via its _custom_ builder. See https://github.com/google/ko and https://github.com/googlecontainertools/skaffold/tree/master/examples/custom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this article after googling some more which covers the process: [*Using go mod download to speed up Golang Docker builds*](https://medium.com/@petomalina/using-go-mod-download-to-speed-up-golang-docker-builds-707591336888)

The gist of the trick is to copy your `go.mod` and `go.sum` files into the container, then run `go mod download` to download dependencies, and then in another step continue with your build.

This works because your the `go.mod` and `go.sum` files do *not* change unless you add more dependencies. So, when the next `RUN` statement happens which is the `go mod download` docker knows that that it can cache this layer. ([Source](https://thenewstack.io/understanding-the-docker-cache-for-faster-builds/))

```
FROM golang:1.13.9-buster as builder

# Make Build dir
RUN mkdir /build
WORKDIR /build

# Copy golang dependency manifests
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .

# Cache the downloaded dependency in the layer.
RUN go mod download

# add the source code
COPY . .
# Build
RUN go build -o app

# Run
FROM debian:buster-slim
COPY --from=builder /build
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["./app"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered exactly the same issue while integrating `skaffold` with `kubebuilder` and the idea to completely resolve this issue was:

1. To install buildkit, for example: `brew install buildkit`;
2. To enable `skaffold` for local build by having something like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v1beta9
kind: Config
build:
  local:
    useBuildkit: true
    useDockerCLI: true
...
```

3. Edit the `Dockerfile` to enable it:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental

# Build the manager binary
FROM golang:1.12.5 as builder

...
# Build
#RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 GO111MODULE=on go build -a -o manager main.go
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/go/pkg/mod --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/go-build CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 GO111MODULE=on go build -o manager main.go
...
```

Then at first time it will still download every dependency but afterwards it will use the cache, which dramatically speeds up the build process.

Comment: buildkit was in alpha/beta last time I checked? Do you know if that's changed?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Grigoriy Mikhalkin. Regarding your performance improvements, I want to name the [Docker Build Enhancements](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) which are based on [moby/buildkit](https://github.com/moby/buildkit). At the time of writing, the tools aren't properly documented, but with some trial and error, you might find your solution.

Using buildkit, you can use a cache in your `RUN` statements in order to reduce the time of subsequent executions. They provide an [example of Go in their docs](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md#example-cache-go-packages), as well. In order to have it work, you have to enable the experimental features for both the Docker daemon and client (described on the link above).

Comment: I will have to give this a try, but this looks specifically like what I need.

Comment: I thought about it again and I think that there might be solutions which aren't that full-blown. Introducing buildkit just to cache some subsequent installs of dependencies is a bit over the top. There are some workarounds, but all of them are a bit hacky for my taste. But it might work for you:
- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8836#issuecomment-255276792 is about copying and archiving the dependency folder for CI usage
You can combine that with multi-stage builds in order to add the commands required to archive etc. to another image. That might be easier for you. And it works in CI, also

Comment: In addition, buildkit doesn't provide any method right now to copy the build cache from a RUN statement to your host machine. That's why its usage in CI environments is tricky. There is a hacky workaround where you just copy the entire buildkitd directoy and store it as an artifact in your CI: 
Someone posted a proof of concept (tried that on my own) on GitHub: https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/156#issuecomment-537492942

Answer (score 0):

It's customary to use [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) for go services. 
So that all dependencies resolved and executable is built at build stage. And final stage is actually running executable. As a result, your final image will be more slim in size. Although, it's not gonna speed up dependency resolution stage.